# Parsing data are Character cracking phenomenon

Tags: python, web-crawler

This is my source code

```
    chrome_driver = webdriver.Chrome('D:/바탕 화면/인턴/python/crwaler/news_crawling/chromedriver.exe')

    response = requests.get(self.get_url() , verify = False)
    root = lxml.html.fromstring(response.content)
    
    for i in range(1,int(page)):
        url = self.get_url().format(i)
        response = requests.get(url , verify = False)
        root = lxml.html.fromstring(response.content)
        
        for j in range(1,15):
            self.title.append(root.xpath('//*[@id="sub_content"]/div[2]/table/tbody/tr[{}]/td[2]/a'.format(j))[0])
            
    chrome_driver.quit()
            
    return self.get_title()
```

When I run this function, the result is as shown below:

```
['ì\x95\x84ë\x8f\x99ë³µì§\x80ë²\x95 ì\x8b\x9cí\x96\x89ë\xa0¹ ì\x9d¼ë¶\x80ê°\x9cì\xa0\x95ë\xa0¹ì\x95\x88 êµ\xadë¬´í\x9a\x8cì\x9d\x98 ì\x9d\x98ê²° (9.22)'
```

and correct result should be:

```
//*[@id="sub_content"]/div[2]/table/tbody/tr[1]/td[2]/a
```

and this html file encoder is utf-8

How can I get the correct return value like this?

```
아동복지법 시행령 일부개정령안 국무회의 의결 (9.22)
```

Comment: what is your input?

Comment: i don't have a any input because i use selenium. if i have say about input, it will be url!

Answer (score 1):

I think it is encoding problem.
Use HTLMParser as follows.

```
hp = lxml.etree.HTMLParser(encoding='utf-8')
lxml.html.fromstring(response.content, parser=hp).text
```

Since the web page is written by Korean, encoding could be 'utf-8', 'cp949', or 'euc-kr'.

Comment: Ok. If this answer is helpful to your internship (Yes. I am also Korean...ㅎㅎ..), upvote and select this answer